# Concatenating strings in two lists to create a third list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have two lists of items, can you please guide me how I can concatenate values of both  and add concatenated value into third list as a value.

For example if `List<string> From` has  `A,B,C` and `List<string> To` has `1,2,3` then `List<string> All` should have `A1,B2,C3`. I'd preferably like to use a lambda expression.

Answer (score 4):

Use Linq's [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method:

```
using System.Linq;
...

var list1 = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
var list2 = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" };
var list3 = list1.Zip(list2, (x, y) => x + y).ToList(); // { "A1", "B2", "C3" }
```

Answer (score 4):

That's not *concatenation* - that's matching two sequences pairwise. You do it with LINQ's [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

> `Zip` applies a specified function to the corresponding elements of two sequences, producing a sequence of the results.

```
var res = from.Zip(to, (a,b) => a + b).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If item's count are equal in both lists then you can do:

```
var list3 = list1.Select((item, index) => item + list2[index]).ToList();
```